# MEteor: CollectionFS (beginner) can't read collection

Tags: meteor

I'm a starting Meteor developer and currently looking into ways for file upload, and came across collectionFS. I've followed the examples but can't seem to explore the collection like I would with a normal collection

Defined a collection with:

```
var Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```

and published it:

```
Meteor.publish('images', function() {
return Images.find();
});
```

Trying to find it in console or mongodb gives the following error

```
Images.find()
ReferenceError: Images is not defined
images.find()
ReferenceError: images is not defined
```

Normal Meteor collections are working. When I replace FS.Collection with Meteor.collection it does work

**how can I explore the collection?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables defined with `var` kayword are scoped to the file they are defined in. Just replace `var Images` with `Images`.

Comment: I still get the same result Images is not defined. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: normal Meteor collections are working. When I replace FS.Collection with Meteor.collection it does work

Comment: Works now apart from the var global scope also had a small typo somewhere else thanks for help.